# Inserting Information into Parent/Child Tables via a Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Hello I'm working on a database assignment and I'm stuck on how to do this one stored procedure. Although It works, sort of...

> DELIMITER //

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddANewCustomer(IN firstName char(20), IN lastName char(20), IN companyName char(45), IN streetAddress char(60), IN city char(30), IN province char(45), IN postalCode char(6), IN phoneNumber int(10))

BEGIN
        DECLARE PersonID INT;

        SELECT idPerson FROM Persons WHERE Persons.firstName = firstName AND Persons.lastName = lastName INTO PersonID;

        IF PersonID IS NULL THEN

        INSERT INTO Persons(firstName, lastName, streetAddress, city, province, postalCode, phoneNumber) VALUES (firstName, lastName, streetAddress, City, Province, postalCode, phoneNumber);

        SELECT idPerson FROM Persons WHERE firstName = firstName AND lastName = lastName INTO PersonID;

        END IF;

        INSERT INTO Customers(idCustomer, companyName) VALUES (Last_Insert_ID(), companyName);

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Basically I'm working with Super/Sub types. I want to take the information from the user and then update my parent table (Persons) and pass on the remaining information to my child table (Customers). idPerson is the auto-incrementing PK for Persons table, and I want to use that as a PK/FK for the Customers table's id, idCustomer.

If I run the procedure once, it'll spit out an error 'Result consist of more than one row' and only the Parent table gets updated... But if I run it again, it'll update the Child table properly. Which makes me think that the Last_Insert_ID() parameter is null the first time around and the idPerson only gets updated after the procedure is done.

I've researched for a fix all night and now I'm absolutely stumped on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch.

> Basically I'm working with Super/Sub
>   types.

I don't think so, but I could be wrong. *Customer* usually describes a relationship between two parties, one a buyer and the other a seller.

> If I run the procedure once, it'll
>   spit out an error 'Result consist of
>   more than one row'

What do you think that means?  Does this query return any rows?

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, count(*)
FROM Persons
GROUP BY lastname, firstname
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

You check for a NULL id number,

```
IF PersonID IS NULL THEN
```

but you ignore the possibility that your SELECT statement might return 2 or 3 or 42 different id numbers, all for people who have the same first and last name. Is that wise? Phrased another way, do you have a UNIQUE constraint on {firstname, lastname}?

If PersonID is null, you insert a row into Persons, which sets a value that LAST_INSERT_ID() can return. But your second INSERT tries to use LAST_INSERT_ID() without regard to whether a row was previously inserted into Persons.

Finally, you have two slightly different versions of

```
SELECT idPerson 
FROM Persons 
WHERE Persons.firstName = firstName 
  AND Persons.lastName = lastName 
INTO PersonID;
```

I'm pretty sure you need one at most.